# How to catch all types of exception in one single catch block?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, exception

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do what you want here

    //When type of exception is System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException
    //if (ex.Code.Name.Equals("Client"))
    //{
    //      msg = "service's function not exist";
    //}
    //else if (ex.Code.Name.Equals("Server"))
    //{
    //     msg = "function error"
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //     msg = "unknown";
    //}
    //MessageBox.Show(msg, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

**But ex is not System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException so I cannot call ex.Code.Name.Equals("Client")**


//When System.Net.WebException
//switch (ex.Status)
//{
//   case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure:
//              do some thing
                break;
//   case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                //do some thing
                break;
//    case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError:
            switch (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode)
            {
                  case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                        //do some thing
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                        //do some thing
                        break;
                    case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                        //do some thing
                        break;
                    default:
                        //do some thing
                        break;
                }
                break;
            default:
                //do some thing
                break;
        }
}
```

**But Exception is not System.Net.WebException. So cannot call ex.Status**

**My problem:**

I have a Smartclient software include WindowsForm as client and a webservice as server.
Client and Server both are n-tiers application
I have tested and found that has any problem when call service from Client

1. in app.config: service's path wrrong . I catch *System.NotSupportedException*
2. Or when the server cannot connect: *System.Net.WebExceptionStatus*
3. Server's webconfig is wrong : *System.InvalidOperationException*
4. Service throws an exception: *System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException*
   ...

**My Idea**

I call the Exception that as representative of all other exception types is *representativeAlException*

I have namespace : Common and two classese *representativeAlException.cs* and *BusinessExceptionHandler.cs*

Make a common function with a param as (representativeAlException ex)

```
            try
            {
                Err_LogCheck.Service1.Service1 service = new Err_LogCheck.Service1.Service1();
                return service.getDeviceByZero(ZERO);
            }
            catch (Common.representativeAlException ex)
            {
                Common.BusinessExceptionHandler.ProcessException(ex);
            }
```

**What I want to do**

Where the service is called. Only one catch block can handler for all type of Exception

in *ProcessException(representativeAlException ex)* function

```
switch (ex)
{
case System.InvalidOperationException:
 //Do some thing
 break;
case System.NotSupportedException:
 //Do some thing
 break;
case System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
 //do some thing
 break;
...
...
```

Comment: Try my answer, I cast ex to specific exception so you can use the methods and properties of that specific exception.

Comment: Seriously, **don't** do a catch-all exception block. It's a bad programming practice. Only catch specific exceptions.

Comment: i do catch-all in any where. But the exception is separated to any type in a common function

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To handle all exception, use Exception class.

```
try
{

}
catch(Exception ex)
{
     switch (ex.GetType().ToString())
     {
         case "System.InvalidOperationException":
              //cast ex to specific type of exception to use it's properties
              ((InvalidOperationException)ex).SomeMethod();
         break;
         case "System.NotSupportedException":
             ((System.NotSupportedException)ex).AnotherMethod();
         break;
         case "System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException":
             ((System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException)ex).OtherMethod();
         break;
     }

}
```

Why can't you just use multiple catch block anyway?

Comment: ex is not Exception. "I call the Exception that as representative of all other exception types is representativeAlException".   My catch block is : catch (Common.representativeAlException ex)

Comment: Your question is not clear so I assumed you want to handle all types of exception. I'm trying to help but all I get is downvote.

Comment: i am sorry because of my bad english. I want to do that: where the webservice is called, using only one catch block instead of many catch block for many exception types. And in my common function, i will check type of exception and send each message to end-user

Comment: Have you tried my codes, it's meant to catch all types of exception.

Comment: This is the answer, best as I can tell, based on the question. I'm not sure why it got downvoted.

Comment: @dpp, your answer is OK, but it would be better to use the syntax that was designed for this.   Get rid of the exception type altogether.   i.e.  `try {} catch {}`.  C# does not require you to specify the exception you are trying to catch.

Comment: i written alot. But cannot post my answer. So sorry

Comment: @user1299527, I understand that English is not your first language, but reading "i written alot. But cannot post my answer. So sorry" I do not understand what you are getting at.

Comment: thank you. I have edited my question's content. Hope that you can understand my question

Comment: SoapException is derived from SystemException which is derived from Exception, is it not? Why couldn't the try-catch block catch the SoapException?

Comment: SoapException : SystemException, SystemException : Exception. But if catch (Exception ex) so ex has not properties of SoapException. I think catch Exception can catch any exception types but can not using Exception as  SoapException when catch with Exception  instead of SoapException

Comment: No, no, no. ex will have the properties of SoapException if the exception catched is SoapException, we are just using Exception so that we can catch different types of exception.

Comment: @user1299527 Try the codes above, cast ex to specific exception so you can use the properties of that specific exception.

Comment: dpp , i want to vote you. But cannot. Because of not enough reputation. thank! If Using multiple catch block, i have to write many code in any where the service is called. Only one catch block. And i build a common function. To detach the type of exception. And return the best message to end-user.

Comment: It's okay, you're welcome. It's not about the votes anyway. :)

Comment: Just check my post as answer when you can.

Comment: there's a white check on the upper left part of my post, just check it, if you can't just leave it, it's fine with me.

Comment: I think this could be improved with usage of nameof() - removes lack of typing when checking for matches.

Answer (score 10):

## This is now a language feature. Just use a switch/case statement

The asker's first attempt, shown commented out in the code snippet in the question, is now the easiest and in my opinion best way to do this.

I actually came across this question while trying to figure out what Resharper had done with one of its suggested improvements. I'm still not 100% sure on the terminology involved as the only documentation I could find was explaining [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#pattern-matching-with-switch-and-is) and only mentions in passing the "pattern matching with the is and switch keywords" that is also being performed.

I had started, as Onkel-j reccomends, with a chain of 'if ex is Type':

```
try
{
    doWork();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex is SpecificExceptionType)
    {
        //todo
    }
    else 
    {
        //etc
    }
}
```

but resharper suggested I let it change this to a switch/case:

```
try
{
    doWork();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex)
    {
        case SpecificExceptionType _:
            //todo
            break;            
        default:
            //etc
            break;
    }
}
```

Resharper has used [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards#pattern-matching-with-switch-and-is) to do a sort of *automatic* ***is*** and toss out the unused variable. If you need to actually use the exception **as** the specific type, give it a name in place of the underscore:

```
try
{
    doWork();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    switch (ex)
    {
        case SpecificExceptionType specific:
            HandleSpecificException(specific);
            break;            
        default:
            //etc
            break;
    }
}
```

Or to answer the original question:

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do what you want here
    
    switch(ex)
    {
        case System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException soapEx:        
            if (soapEx.Code.Name.Equals("Client"))
            {
                  msg = "service's function not exist";
            }
            else if (soapEx.Code.Name.Equals("Server"))
            {
                 msg = "function error"
            }
            else
            {
                 msg = "unknown";
            }
            MessageBox.Show(msg, "error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);    
            break;
        case System.Net.WebException webEx:
            switch (webEx.Status)
            {
               case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ConnectFailure:
                    //do some thing
                    break;
               case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.Timeout:
                    //do some thing
                    break;
                case System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError:
                    switch (((System.Net.HttpWebResponse)webEx.Response).StatusCode)
                    {
                        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound:
                            //do some thing
                            break;
                        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable:
                            //do some thing
                            break;
                        case System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized:
                            //do some thing
                            break;
                        default:
                            //do some thing
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    //do some thing
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            //etc
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

***User2808350*** is correct that try catch blocks can have many different catches for a reason, however sometimes you find you are repeating yourself (DRY) when using this pattern.

An alternative that can result in concise, readable code is to use the **is** operator which evaluates to true if your exception is an instance of a particular type or one that derives from that type. Unfortunately it's not possible to use the **is** operator in a switch block, so you have to use if-then-else.

Here is an example where I test the exception type and set the exit code accordingly.

```
try
{
    // try something
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    if (e is FileNotFoundException)
        Environment.ExitCode = 2;
    else if (e is InvalidOperationException)
        Environment.ExitCode = 1;
    else
        Environment.ExitCode = 42;
    throw;
}
```

Comment: Upvoting, because mentioning the DRY principle. Which is why I ended up doing it this way.

Comment: Reading this exact code is noticeably harder compared to switch statements, which can be inlined due to short lines. While this is not wrong, I doubt using "is" is worth the added reading complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Should use

```
try {

    ....

}
catch (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
 //do some thing
}    
catch (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable)
{
 //do some thing
}

catch (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
{
 //do some thing
}

catch (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
 //do some thing
}    
catch (Exception)
{
 //do some thing
}
```

It's better that using swicth

Comment: This doesn't answer original question, neither any proof for "this way is better" was provided.